# `xev` doesn't register my `Fn+F4` keypress? How to bind this combination?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, kubuntu, keyboard-event

My question is simple. `xev` isn't registering `Fn+F4` keypress on my Asus FX505DT running Kubuntu 19.10.
So, how shall I proceed with solving this issue?

Comment: Some FN keys on laptops are handled directly by some firmware and do not even reach the OS. Check by switching to a virtual terminal with Ctrl-Alt-Fx and running the showkeys program

Comment: Thanks for the response, using `showkey` I finally got some response: `248`.

Comment: Additionally, I found out that `showkey` and `xev` both don't register `Fn+F5`. How should I go about fixing that?

Comment: **Update**: Using `evtest`, I've found that keysym `248` comes under a separate device named as **Asus WMI hotkeys**. How can I use this input with i3wm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After this much much time, I've figured out how to make this `Fn` + `F4` keypress recognizable by `xev`.
The issue started with this key combination having the keycode `248` which isn't interpreted by the X Window system since [it only accepts keycodes between `8 - 255`](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/xproto/x11protocol.html#Keyboards).

> Apparently, `248` is the keycode interpreted by `showkey` in the virtual console and `8` has to be added to it, which makes it greater than `255`. (I don't have any reference for this but I've read this on many threads.)

Once I found out the issue, the solution was simple, to re-allocate the `Fn`+`F4` keypress somewhere between `8 - 255`. I found the unassigned keycodes using `xmodmap -pke`, and in my case I went with `120`.
Afterwards, I proceeded using this [tutorial](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Map_scancodes_to_keycodes#Using_udev).

> In my case, `showkey -s` wan't returning anything so I had to use `getkeycodes`.

Once the keycode `120` was assigned to `Fn` + `F4`, I assigned the `XF86AudioMicMute` symbol to it using `xmodmap`.