# Lenovo screen backlight can not set with brightness function Fn keys

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel, laptop, backlight

Being aware of that this is partially a known issue, since each is individual and different, the problem is as following:

On my Lenovo Laptop with Linux Mint the backlight cannot be set using Fn+F6/F7. These keys are not detected at all, neither by `xev` nor by `acpi_listen`. However other key combinations like Fn+F3 for volume up is detected by both commands. So it is a more low-level issue, I am afraid.
On the other hand, this works well:

- `echo 10000 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness` and as well
- with the GUI slider in `mate-power-preferences` works perfectly.
- `xdotool key 232`  or `xdotool key XF86MonBrightnessDown`

More detailed:

- I tried many boot combinations (yes I updated GRUB and did reboot, as described in this troubleshooting [wiki.ubuntu.com Debugging/Backlight](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Debugging/Backlight))
- I tried adding files in /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/ as recommended (`80-backlight.conf` using both "Backlight"       "ideapad" and "intel_backlight", or `20-intel.conf`)

`uname -a` yields: `Linux Lenovo-V14-G2-ITL 5.8.0-53-generic #60~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 6 09:52:46 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

These are the available backlights (which can be written using cat)

```
$ ls /sys/class/backlight/
ideapad  intel_backlight
```

This is my current configuration

```
$ cat /proc/cmdline
BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-5.8.0-53-generic root=/dev/mapper/vgmint-root ro pcie_aspm=force acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor quiet splash
```

I tried these (as well individually and with many combinations, only visible effect is that the output of `ls /sys/class/backlight/` is  changing)

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="pcie_aspm=force acpi_osi=linux acpi_backlight=vendor video.use_native_backlight=1"
```

Comment: Not sure, but if `xev` doesn't register your keypresses, I don't think there's much you can do. I guess you have two options: 1) Figuring out why `xev` does not register these keys; or 2) use different keys to bind a command (I had best experiences with `xbacklight`).

Comment: `xev` not registering keypress might be more common than I thought, see e.g. here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/584299/58056

Comment: The behaviour is similar to this https://askubuntu.com/questions/830948/lenovo-ideapad-brightness-keys-not-generating-any-events-in-ubuntu-16-04-1 however I am stuck at the transition to the step where xev detects the keys . `xdotool key 232` works well! And xmodmap -pke shows the brightness keys but how do I get the scancodes? With getkeycodes I see that there is not an entry for keycode=232 (so there is no scancode associated with it?)

Answer (score 2):

I like to control backlight with use of the `light` utility (in Ubuntu, it is in the package [`light`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/light)).

So on sway, Ubuntu, I did this:

```
sudo apt install light
vim .config/sway/config
```

Add these lines somewhere in `.config/sway/config` (or in `/etc/sway/config` if you have nothing in your home):

```
#
# Backlight controll using thinkpad Fn+F5 and Fn+F6
#
    # Increase and decrease backlight in 4% steps
    bindsym XF86MonBrightnessUp exec sudo light -A 4
    bindsym XF86MonBrightnessDown exec sudo light -U 4
```

In case, you need to be root for using light, these commands would point you to solution:

```
light -A 5 -v 3
ls -alh /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
sudo usermod -aG video $USER
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but I cannot leave comments so I have to use answer. What Lenovo model is it?

See if this works (and, as always, make a backup of any configuration file before modifying it):

1. `echo options hid_apple fnmode=0 | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/hid_apple.conf`
2. `sudo update-initramfs -u`
3. Reboot

EDIT: If `fnmode=0` doesn't work, you can try `fnmode=2`.

Comment: It's a Lenovo machine, probably a V14 G2-ITL as the hostname suggests. Why do you think options for an [Apple keyboard](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/407501/make-apple-keyboard-settings-persistent-in-hid-apple-parameters) would work here?

Comment: I have had the same problem with a layered keyboard (none of the my products are Apple, either) where some of the buttons didn't work when I pressed `Fn`. Changing the `conf` file and updating the `initramfs` (and rebooting) worked for me. Thought it might be worth a shot for you as well. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

What I do with mine:

```
#!/bin/bash

# sputnick 2023

devvideo=$(xrandr | awk '$2 == "connected"{print $1;exit}')

if ! val=$(cat ~/.config/xrandr/brightness 2>/dev/null); then
    mkdir -p ~/.config/xrandr
    echo 0.90 > ~/.config/xrandr/brightness
    val=0.90
fi

case $1 in
    -) val="0$(bc <<< $val-0.05)"  ;;
    +) val="0$(bc <<< $val+0.05)"  ;;
esac

if ((${val#*.} <= 20 || ${val#*.} >= 100 )); then
    echo >&2 ERR
    exit 1
fi

echo $val | tee ~/.config/xrandr/brightness
exec xrandr --output $devvideo --brightness +$val
```

then you set a keyboard shorthand to run this script in your Window Manager settings. Chosen <kbd>Ctrl+fn6</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl+fn7</kbd>.

The mandatory parameter is `+` or `-`. Let's [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)

Answer (score 0):

Faced with a similar problem on...

- i3
- 6.5.9-arch2-1
- Lenovo IdeaPad 5 Pro 14ACN6

... I found that while `xev` does not identify the function keys I **can** bind them ...

```
    # backlight control
    bindsym XF86MonBrightnessUp exec display.sh 0.1
    bindsym XF86MonBrightnessDown exec sh display.sh -0.1
```

...to a very simple script ....

```
#!/bin/bash

increment="$1"
brightness=$(xrandr --verbose | sed -n "/eDP/{n;n;n;n;n;s/.*: //p}")
xrandr --output eDP --brightness $(echo "$brightness + $increment " | bc)
```

As you can probably guess, I also had issues writing to the '/sys/' backlight controls and so used a nasty hack with `xrandr`.

Not quite sure how to implement keybindings in Mint (maybe [like this?](https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/356)) but like you I tried many things and since binding worked it was good enough.

**Update - fix for the brightness keys**

I found that installing `acpi_call-dkms` resolved my Fn key issue with brightness control thanks to the [Archwiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Lenovo_IdeaPad_5_Pro_14ACN6#ACPI_method_2). You may find an equivalent in your repository.

**As an aside - who needs the brightness keys anyway?**

I found the above fix while fiddling to use my webcam as a sensor and automatically control the screen brightness (via systemd timer, service and script), but came across `clight-gui` over at [Github](https://github.com/nullobsi/clight-gui) which allows custom independent brightness ramps on battery and AC for both keyboard and backlight driven by ambient light. Solved all of my needs.

My thanks to @FedeDP and @nullobsi over at Github.